# Java Generic on Class

Tags: java, mysql, generics, interface, implements

How to run a anonymous method from class .

For instance,

I have a class

```
Class A {
   void Save(){
     //do something
   }
}


Class B {
       void Save(){
         //do something
       }
    }
```

When I getting the object from somewhere:

```
Object something = (could be A or B both because object can accept anything.)
something.Save() //doesn't work. To solve this I could use inheritance(abstract class or Interface) but if I want to do it anonymously
```

Like in VB

```
object Form = SomeRandomForm
Form.Save() // anonymously no need to inherit
```

Is it possible in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what it is exactly that you mean (some code might help), but basically you just define the generics on the interface and the concrete type on the panels:

```
interface MyInterface<T> { ... }

class StringPanel extends JPanel implements MyInterface<String> { ... }
```

The rest is up to you.